# Django-registration. The activation link sent is missing my app name

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I am haviing issues with the django-registration module. When a user tries to register, the activation link that he receives in his email is not correct. I mean, for the link to work, I have to manually add my app's name right after the domain name.

Let me explain this with an example:

This is the main's page url (note the "HELLOPROJECT"):
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/HELLOPROJECT/index`

This is the registration url (note the "HELLOPROJECT"):
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/HELLOPROJECT/accounts/register/`

And this is the activation url sent in the email (note there is no "HELLOPROJECT"):
    `http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/activate/3a97ec229308b0112cb6e1ef16f8ab32df667b9c/`

If I click the above link, an error occurs. I have to manually add the "HELLOPROJECT" for the link to work properly and register the user.

So, why does this happen? How can I solve it?

Comment: Are you using Apache2/mod_wsgi, or running a development server?

Comment: @rofls, I am using the Django's development server.

Comment: Based on the quick start guide, do you need to set the site object in your registration/activation_email.txt template? To check, what is the URL in your email subject?

Comment: @Talvalin,the URL in the email's subject is "Activate your djangoproject.com account - you have 7 days!"

Comment: @Talvalin I am looking for the "registration/activation_email.txt" file but can't manage to find it.

Comment: can you post your `urls.py`? (the main one)

Comment: @Talvalin, you were aiming in the right direction, thank you. In the end it was as simple as editing the registration/activation_email.txt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The activation email template includes

```
{{site}}/accounts/activate/{{ activation_key }}/
```

Firstly make sure you have your copy of templates for registration correct. Then make sure your `SITE_ID` in `settings.py` matches the `site` you created. The `djangoproject.com` site is probably default and has id 1. If you edited the name of it to match your site, the id will remain same, if you add a new one find the new id and set your `SITE_ID` to that.

**site**

> An object representing the site on which the user registered;
>   depending on whether django.contrib.sites is installed, this may be an
>   instance of either django.contrib.sites.models.Site (if the sites
>   application is installed) or django.contrib.sites.models.RequestSite
>   (if not). Consult the documentation for the Django sites framework for
>   details regarding these objects' interface

Comment: Thank you Pratik. As it turns out, the solution to my issue consisted in editing the activation_email.txt